# Use of '&' operator before a function name in C++

Tags: c++, function, reference

A reference defines an alternative name for an object. A reference type “refers to”
another type. We define a reference type by writing a declarator of the form `&d`,
where `d` is the name being declared.

The next thing is a reference is not an object. Instead, a reference is just another name for an already existing object. So we'll use these references to pass the parameter by reference so that it directly effect the actual parameters.

**Question:**
What happens when we use a reference (`&`) *before* a function name?

I'm a little bit confused, as in my opinion it will return the alias of return (variable name). Or am I wrong?.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, 
                                std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
```

Comment: Remember to tag with C *or* C++. They are different languages (which is why there is no c-or-c++ tag). Also, since C *doesn't have* references in the C++ sense .. (it's the "address-of" operator here)

Comment: I wonder why you all want to close this. "What happens when we use a reference before a function name" is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: @FUZxxl It's because it's difficult to tell what question is being asked.  "Before a function name" in what context?  A code example would help.

Comment: @Maxprm So your response is to just close it instead of asking for clarification? YOu know, "unclear what you're asking" is not the same as "I can't answer this question".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In **C++**, when the ref-sign (`&`) is used before the function name in the *declaration* of a function it is associated with the return value of the function and means that the function will *return by reference*.

```
int& foo(); // Function will return an int by reference.
```

When not used within a declaration context, putting the ref-sign before a function name results in calling the *address-of* operator returning the address of the function. This can be used to e.g. create a pointer to a function.

```
// Some function.
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    // Declare type func_ptr_t as pointer to function of type int(int, int).
    using func_ptr_t = std::add_pointer<int(int, int)>::type;

    func_ptr_t func = &sum; // Declare func as pointer to sum using address-of.
    int sum = func(1, 2);   // Initialize variable sum with return value of func.
}
```

In **C**, the only use of `&` is for the address-of operator. References does *not* exist in the C language.

Answer (score 9):

In `C`, `&func` where `func` is a function evaluates to the address of the function which can be assigned to a function pointer which points to a function having the same signature as the function `func`.

```
int func(float);

int (*fp)(float) = &func; 
// equivalent to
int (*fp)(float) = func;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'// return the plural version of word if ctr is greater than 1
string make_plural(size_t ctr, const string &word,
                           const string &ending)
{
    return (ctr > 1) ? word + ending : word;
}'
```

The return type of this function is string, which means the return value is copied to
the call site. This function returns a copy of word, or it returns an unnamed
temporary string that results from adding word and ending.

As with any other reference, when a function returns a reference, that reference is
just another name for the object to which it refers. As an example, consider a function
that returns a reference to the shorter of its two string parameters:

```
'// return a reference to the shorter of two strings
const string &shorterString(const string &s1, const string
&s2)
{
    return s1.size() <= s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}'
```

The parameters and return type are references to const string. The strings are
not copied when the function is called or when the result is returned.

Never Return a Reference or Pointer to a Local Object

When a function completes, its storage is freed. After a function
terminates, references to local objects refer to memory that is no longer valid: